# How to change wallet-adapter-react-ui WalletBultiButton styling

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

This is how the current multi-button looks like on my page
[image]

however I want to override not just the styling, but also change the text and or the make the button an image. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Create a `wallet.css` file copy past the following snippet in the CSS file:

```
 .wallet-button{
    border: 2px solid black !important;
    color: black !important;
 }
  
 .wallet-button:hover {
   border: 2px solid grey !important;
   color: white !important;
 }
```

Step 2: Import CSS file in the component (make sure path to file is correct):

`import "./wallet.css";`

Step 3: Add class in `WalletMultiButton` component:

```
<WalletMultiButton  
   className="wallet-button"  
/>
```

Comment: Now, you can play with CSS as per your requirements.